# How to make a remove method for a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I am currently writing a Employee store and I need to be able to remove contents of the store.

How would I do that?

I already have a remove method using the key to remove it.  But as I found this code on the internet I have no idea how to use it.

Here is my code:

**MainApp**

```
public class MainApp
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new MainApp().start();

    }
    public void start()
    {
        EmployeeStore Store = new EmployeeStore();
        Store.add(new Employee ("James O' Carroll", 18,"hotmail.com"));

        Store.add(new Employee ("Andy Carroll", 1171,"yahoo.com"));

        Store.add(new Employee ("Luis Suarez", 7,"gmail.com"));
        Store.print();
        Store.clear();
        Store.print();

        Store.add(new Employee ("James O' Carroll", 18,"hotmail.com"));

        Store.add(new Employee ("Andy Carroll", 1171,"yahoo.com"));

        Store.add(new Employee ("Luis Suarez", 7,"gmail.com"));

        Store.print();
        Store.remove();


    }

}
```

**EmployeeStore**

```
//Imports.
import java.util.HashMap;
//********************************************************************
import java.util.Map;

public class EmployeeStore 
{
    HashMap<String, Employee> map;

//Constructor.  
    public EmployeeStore()
    {
        map = new HashMap<String,Employee>();
    }
//********************************************************************
//Hashmap Methods.
//Add to the Hashmap : Employee.
    public void add(Employee obj)
    {

        map.put(obj.getEmployeeName(), obj);
    }
//********************************************************************
//Remove from the Hashmap : Employee.
    public void remove(String key)
    {
      //Remove the Employee by name.
        map.remove(key);
    }
//********************************************************************
//Clear the Hashmap : Employee.
    public void clear()
    {
        map.clear();
    }
    //********************************************************************
//Print the Hashmap : Employee. 
    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("\n********Employee's in the Company.********");
        for (Employee employee : map.values())
        {
            System.out.println("Employee Name:\t" + employee.getEmployeeName());
            System.out.println("Employee Id:\t" + employee.getEmployeeId());
            System.out.println("E-mail:\t"+ employee.getEmployeeEmail());
        }

    }


//********************************************************************  
//********************************************************************


}
```

**Employee**

```
//Imports:

//********************************************************************
//Employee Class.
public class Employee
{
//Variables.
    private String employeeName;
    private int employeeId;
    private String employeeEmail;
//********************************************************************  
//Constructor.
    public Employee(String employeeName, int employeeId, String employeeEmail) 
    {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
        this.employeeEmail = employeeEmail;
    }
//********************************************************************
//Getters.
    public String getEmployeeEmail() {
        return employeeEmail;
    }
    public void setEmployeeEmail(String employeeEmail) {
        this.employeeEmail = employeeEmail;
    }
    public String getEmployeeName() {
        return employeeName;
    }
    public int getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }
//********************************************************************
//toString method.
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [employeeName=" + employeeName + ", employeeId="
                + employeeId + ", employeeEmail=" + employeeEmail + "]";
    }
//********************************************************************





}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  You already have a `remove()` method, so what else do you need?

Comment: The Employee Store is in the Code.  I will make it clearer by adding comments.

Comment: I don't understand how to use the remove method in the MainApp.  I need to delete say the Andy Carroll.  I dont know how to do that.

Comment: Deleting Andy Carroll is certainly a good idea. :) You'd have to call `Store.remove( "Andy Carroll" );`

Comment: As an aside, your variables should start with a lowercase letter, e.g. `store` instead of `Store`. It's a convention almost everyone coding in Java adheres to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `EmployeeStore` uses a `HashMap` to store the employees. Every employees is identified by its name in the map. To remove an employee, you just need to call `EmployeeStore.remove(String employeeName)`.

```
EmployeeStore employeeStore = new EmployeeStore();
employeeStore.add(new Employee ("James O' Carroll", 18,"hotmail.com"));
employeeStore.add(new Employee ("Andy Carroll", 1171,"yahoo.com"));
employeeStore.add(new Employee ("Luis Suarez", 7,"gmail.com"));

// Remove a certain employee
employeeStore.remove("Andy Carroll");

// Remove all employees
employeeStore.clear();
```

There are 2 things you should notice:

1 - The current implementation does not allow two or more employees have the same name, since the names are being used as keys in the map.

2 - When you call the `remove` method, you have to supply the exact name, since `String` equality in Java is case-sensitive.

You may also want to take a look at [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html).

Comment: Thanks so much you made that understandable for me.

Answer (score 0):

A. Why not use the remove method of HashMap to solve this issue? 
B. In addition, maybe you would like to perform remove by some criteria - for this you will have to iterate on the map, find the relevant entry, get its key, and call remove as stated at section A

Comment: If you would like to ask for clarification on the question, please do so in a comment, not an answer.